# expose typedef for function in cpp for template class

Tags: c++

this code compiled fine with gcc

foo.h

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
    static const int n = 10;
};

template<typename T>
class Child : public Base
{
    typedef Base<T> base_t;

    void Compute(Matrix<base_t::n, base_t::n>& M);
}
```

foo.cpp

```
template<typename T>
Child<T>::Compute(Matrix<base_t::n, base_t::n>& M)
{}
```

But with VS2019, it gaves error C2244: unable to match function definition to an existing declaration. It works if in cpp one defines

```
Child<T>::Compute(Matrix<Child<T>::base_t::n, Child<T>::base_t::n>& M)
```

But this looks ugly. Nevertheless why gcc could infer the base_t at the first place? Is there a flag with VS that makes it behave the same as gcc in this aspect`?

Comment: Defining the template in a .cpp file shouldn't work in the first place (you won't be able to use it in other .cpp files, so it shouldn't be in the header). Most of the time when you have a member function declaration like this, it's easier to put an inline definition directly in the class.

Comment: It does not look ugly, it's a correct code. `base_t::n` is seen in Child scope when the member function is  declared, and is seen in the global scope when the member function is defined.